# JavaFX - Customized Button Shape

Tags: java, javafx

I want a `Button` to look like below shape in **JavaFX**,

[image]

with, `-fx-background-radius: 20;` i am able to achieve the corner radius .

How should i proceed further to get the above shaped `Button`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the -fx-shape property.

You can find it in Oracle's reference guide: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#references

This is is also useful to understand how to draw the "path" associated with your shape: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html

You may want to use an SVG editor for your shape's path; for example: https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit

something like this should do the trick; you should need to add the curves
-fx-shape: "M50 100 L150 100 L180 250 L20 250 Z";

Comment: i am able to do it with "M 250 200 Q 250 350 400 350 L 700 350 Q 800 350 800 200 Q 800 150 700 150 L 350 150 Q 250 150 250 200 Z"